# Spectrum of a Hamiltonian which is a perturbation of Laplacian

Tags: operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Let $\Delta =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_3^2}$ be the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Consider a self adjoint operator $H$ on complex valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$
$$H\psi=\Delta\psi(x) +i\sum_{p=1}^3A_p(x)\frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x_p} +B(x)\psi(x),$$
where $A_i,B$ are smooth functions.

> I am looking for a precise result of the following approximate form: 
>   (1) if $A_i$ and $B$ are 'small' then the discrete spectrum of $H$ is non-positive. (2) If $A_i,B$ are 'large' then the discrete spectrum of $H$ contains necessarily a positive element.

Comment: Even with the $A_i=0$ and $B(x) \to 0$ at $\infty$ there can be positive eigenvalues, see my answer  [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/85443).